# Flutter - Periodic Location fetch while application in Background state and Terminate state

Tags: android, ios, flutter, geolocation

I want to **fetch** the **location every 30sec** while the **application** in the **background**, as well as the **application**, is **terminated**. I am getting the current location but when the application is going into the background that location has been failed.

Is that any suggestion on how to complete this feature for my application?

I am using a **geolocator: ^7.0.3** plugin in my flutter application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this dependency I think it could help you a lot:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation

Comment: Is there any other free package?